# Unable to push to branch on sourcetree

Tags: git, blockchain, atlassian-sourcetree

I get this error when trying to push

> git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false push -v
>   --tags origin master:master remote: Permission to Eternum101/PharmaCare-System.git denied to JakeNicholasSmith. fatal:
>   unable to access
>   'https://github.com/Eternum101/PharmaCare-System.git/': The requested
>   URL returned error: 403 Pushing to
>   https://github.com/Eternum101/PharmaCare-System.git

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are not authenticated.
take a look at this:

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Entering-in-a-password-in-SourceTree/qaq-p/251748

sorry, i should have commented but i don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

If you get below error while pulling any branch into current branch in sourceTree:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false --no-optional-locks fetch --no-tags origin
The server's host key is not cached. You have no guarantee
that the server is the computer you think it is.
The server's ssh-ed25519 key fingerprint is:
ssh-ed25519 255 SHA256:FNsg*****
If you trust this host, enter "y" to add the key to
```

If you receive the message about the host key is not catched while doing git push/pull operations using SourceTree.
Go to SourceTree Tools -> Options (General Tab) and changing the SSH Client under (under SSH Client Configuration) from PuTTY to OpenSSH will allow the key to be cached without changing anything else.

To save private key: download Putty: [Download PuTTY](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest.html)

1. Once installed, search and open puttygen from your start menu.
2. Select generate, then click and move your mouse around in the blank area.
3. Save private key

Finally run below command: `git config pull.rebase false`